# What is the most efficient way to make changes to a selection of pages in CSS for wordpress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I want to add a background picture to a group of pages in wordpress.

I want to add a different background picture to another group of pages

Currently I am applying it to each individual page using PageID as in the code below. As there are over 1000 pages. Is there are a more simple way to apply to each group of pages?

```
    .page-id-264 #header .logo a,
    .page-id-272 #header .logo a {
     background-image: url("http://www.richcoward.com/newcges/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/NWU-No-Frame.png") !important;
     background-size: 100% !important;
     background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
     height: 86px !important; 
     width: 416px !important;
     }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: are you able to edit the `PHP` that the page templates is written in?

Comment: Why not create page template for each page group?

Comment: yes able to edit the php, yes I think page templates is the best way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution.

Create a custom css (say mystyle.css) file in your theme folder. Add

```
#header .logo a {
     background-image: url("http://www.richcoward.com/newcges/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/NWU-No-Frame.png") !important;
     background-size: 100% !important;
     background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
     height: 86px !important; 
     width: 416px !important;
     }
```

into your mystyle.css. Now, open up your functions.php and enqueue your stylesheet conditionally. Use `is_page()` or `is_page_template()` conditional checks. I believe that you are talking about groups of pages, so I would imagine that you use specific page templates for specific groups, so I would tend to go for `is_page_template`

```
function enqueue_custom_style() {

  if(is_page_template('page-whatever.php')) {

    wp_enqueue_style('my-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/mystyle.css' );

  }
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_style', 999);
```

This should give you an idea

Comment: Thanks Pieter, I did that and its loading the .php file but not loading the .css, do I need to do anything else to register an additional css file? I just copied the custom css above into a new css file but doesn't seem to be working

Comment: No, nothing else needed. Are you maybe using a child theme

Comment: Did you change page-whatever.php to your correct tempalate name

Comment: It is within a child theme, I'm not sure if that makes any difference

Comment: Yes changed it to the template page name

Comment: Updated code. Just one other thing I forgot. Remove all the `!important` from your css.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a filter in your functions.php file to add a class to all the relevant pages. You're still going to have to rattle off each Page ID, but I guess doing it in PHP will keep your CSS smaller (and therefore load faster):

```
// Add specific CSS class by filter
add_filter( 'body_class', 'my_class_names' );
function my_class_names( $classes ) {
    // array of Page IDs
    $pageids = array(264, 272);
    // if 
    if ( is_page( $pageids ) ) {
        // add 'class-name' to the $classes array
        $classes[] = 'class-name';
        // return the $classes array
        return $classes;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, create page templates for each background.